# How to create sprites, programatically without using prefeb?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well . . I have looked for quite a bit long, but everywhere I get the same answer, which is what specifically don't wanna do.

**Here is my problem case:**

I have different-different type of images for different - different sprites. And I am not certain that how much different `sprites(images)` I will have to show. So, I gotta create the sprites and apply textures programmatically at run-time.

Now, I defiantly can't use *prefebs* because it will restrict me with the number of different sprites I can use. And also, changing texture on one sprite prefeb instance in game, will change all the sprites prefeb, that's not acceptable in my case.

Is there a way I can create sprites without having to create static prefeb ?

Where ever I looked for the solution, every time I got the same answer "create a prefeb", which is what can not be done in my case.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use primitive type game objects. And yes, they can be created without using prefabs.
Also if you're just about to use sprites, the primitive type "Plane" would do the same thing you want.

Try the following:-

1. Make an empty game object in your scene, and reposition it to (0,0,0)
2. attach a script with the following code to this empty game object

   ```
   public int numberOfTiles=16;
   Vector3 TilePosition;

   void Start () 
   {
       TilePosition = Vector3.zero;
       for (int i = 1; i<=numberOfnumberOfTiles; i++) 
       {
           GameObject temp = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
           temp.name = "Tile_"+i;
           temp.transform.position = TilePosition;
           temp.transform.Rotate(90f,180f,0,Space.World);
           temp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.66f,1f,0.66f);
           temp.transform.parent = transform;
           Texture2D tex =(Texture2D) Resources.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Resources/Texture/Tile"+i,typeof(Texture2D));
           temp.renderer.material.mainTexture = new Texture2D (640, 960, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
           temp.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
           TilePosition = new Vector3(TilePosition.x,TilePosition.y+(temp.transform.localScale.y*6.59f),TilePosition.z);
       }

   }
   ```

you can change scales as your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this, i tryed to look for loading just 1 sprite out of the sprite sheet but no success

```
public Sprite[] fruitSprites;

void Awake()
    {
        // load all frames in fruitsSprites array
        fruitSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("fruits");
    }

void Start ()
    {
        // create the object
        GameObject fruit = new GameObject();
        // add a "SpriteRenderer" component to the newly created object
        fruit.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        // assign "fruit_9" sprite to it
        fruit.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = fruitSprites[9];
        // to assign the 5th frame
        fruit.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = fruitSprites[5];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this:

```
AnswerSprites.Add(Sprite.Create(answers[j].Texture, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), new Vector2(0, 0), 0.1f));
```